# How to send large file from controller endpoint in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to send a quite large `.zip` archive from my asp.net api controller.
My setup is something like this:
I have an Angular frontend that makes a `GET` request for an archive file.

```typescript
public getArchive(archiveName: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(
        `${this.runtimeConfig.backendApiPath}api/tenants/${this.auth.profile.tid}/objects/archives/${archiveName}`,
        {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({ Authorization: `Bearer ${this.auth.accessToken}` }),
        });
}
```

Then this request is handled in a Backend For Frontend (BFF) api:

```cs
[HttpGet("archives/{archiveName}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetArchive(
    [FromRoute] string archiveName)
{
    try
    {
        var result = await this._objectsServiceClient.GetArchive(archiveName);

        return Ok(result);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex, $"Error while retrieving archive.");
        return BadRequest(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

the service returns a `byte[]` that is coming from a `GET` request from the backend Api:

```cs
public Task<byte[]> GetArchive(string archiveName)
{
    var url = $@"{this.options.BackendUrl}"
                .AppendPathSegments("api", "tenants", $"{this.tenantInfo.TenantId}", "objects", "archives", archiveName)
                .SetQueryParam("api-version", "1.0")
                .ToString();

    var res = this.Get<byte[]>(url);

    return res;
}
```

and the `this.Get<byte[]>` method I have:

```cs
protected async Task<T> Get<T>(string url)
{
    var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri(url));
    await response.EnsureSuccessStatusCodeExtendedAsync();

    var retVal = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>();
    return retVal;
}
```

The backend controller's endpoint has the following code:

```cs
[HttpGet("objects/archives/{archiveName}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetArchive(Guid tenantId, [FromRoute] string archiveName)
{
    using (Infrastructure.Extensions.LoggerExtensions.BeginScope(
               this.logger,
               LoggingScopeField.TenantId(tenantId)))
    {
        try
        {
            var path = new BlobStorageRepoPathBuilder()
                .WithId(tenantId)
                .WithPath("archives")
                .WithId(this.userInfo.UserId)
                .WithPath($"{archiveName}.zip")
                .Build();

            var blob = await this.repo.DownloadAsync(path);

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await blob.Stream.CopyToAsync(ms);
                ms.Position = 0;

                return Ok(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.logger.LogError(ex, "Error occurred during report generation.");
            return this.BadRequest("Error occurred during report generation. Please check the logs.");
        }
    }
}
```

Basically I download the file from a file storage, load it in a `MemoryStream` and send it as a `byte[]`.This works fine with small files (I know that using `MemoryStream` is not the best decision, that's why I want to change that), but when a large file comes (like more than 2GB) I got an `OutOfMemory` exceptions. I found out an [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-7.0#upload-large-files-with-streaming) that describes how to receive a large file, not to send one as a response.

So my question is, how can I handle large (>2GB) files, and remove the `MemoryStream` from the equation

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `return File()` ? No need to download it either, [File()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.file?view=aspnetcore-7.0) can accept a stream

Comment: Where do you download the file from and why? First, GET supports ranges and `File` can handle them, returning only what the client requests. It's a lot safer to download a file in chunks, retrying only those that failed. Cloud providers also support ranges but these have to be specified in the initial request.

Comment: the file is downloaded from a AWS S3 repository. And it is a zip file containing mostly .json, .jpg and .pdf files

Comment: In that case, to support ranges you probably need to change the call to `DownloadAsync` and send the requested range before returning the chunk with `return File(...)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer as well it is working with relatively small files, but this is not working for me for larger files (> 3GB)

Comment: What does `it's not working for me` mean? It gets interrupted? Yes, either the AWS connection or the client-to-server connection is bound to get interrupted for such large files. That's why download managers download files in chunks, so they can retry chunks that get interrupted. That includes the AWS SDK download manager

Comment: If you have multi-GB articles, downloading it locally then sending it to the caller isn't a great choice. You pay for bandwidth *twice* - once for the AWS egress and once for your server's outbound bandwidth. You also need to ensure retries and recovery on *two* long connections. It's probably better to create a shareable link, send it to the client and have the client get the file.

Comment: Check [Upload or download large files to and from Amazon S3 using an AWS SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example_s3_Scenario_UsingLargeFiles_section.html) too. `TransferUtility` downloads chunks behind the scenes, verifies and retries them as necessary, so the download can finish even if interrupted. With 3GB interruptions are almost guaranteed. In the end, the code calls [GetObjectResponse.WriteResponseStreamToFileAsync](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/74ece25002a66ec39f33e1bb98eeb5a718f6e4e3/sdk/src/Services/S3/Custom/Model/GetObjectResponse.cs#L756)

Comment: Notice how the code validates the chunk size. HTTP Response streams aren't file streams. The bytes can just stop coming without any indication, or because an intermediate proxy stopped them.

Comment: Thanks for all the explanation. I'll surely consider them!! "It's probably better to create a shareable link, send it to the client and have the client get the file" I think this is the best solution in my opinion, but surely this is a decision our solution architects have to make! Thanks again for the answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure how the internals of `this.repo.DownloadAsync` work since it's not included in your question, but it appears that it just provides the direct IO response stream from the file source (which looks like Azure Blob Storage). If that's the case, why not just stream the file to the client?:

```cs
var blob = await this.repo.DownloadAsync(path);
return File(blob.Stream, "application/zip", fileDownloadName: $"{archiveName}.zip");
```

From your comment on this answer, it seems like `this.repo.DownloadAsync` is using `HttpClient` based on your comment. To directly get the stream from `HttpClient` you can use the following code:

```cs
HttpClient client; // your HttpClient instance that you're already using
var stream = await client.GetStreamAsync(theUrl);
```

The stream will be returned to you after the HTTP response readers have been received, and then you can return this to your controller method, and then to the client using `return File` to directly stream the result through your server without first downloading it.

Comment: the problem I face now is how to receive the file in the BFF and resend it to the client `var retVal = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>();`

Comment: Is `response` from `HttpClient`?

Comment: @Julian If that's the case, please see my follow-up edit.

Comment: Hi there, I was able to test the scenario, it is working like a charm, but when I try to do it with large file (more than 3GB), the api (BFF) returns `400 BadRequest`. Is there any way that this can be fixed?

Comment: @Julian I expect some error is being caught by your try/catch and then returned as a 400 BadRequest as per your logic. Without knowing the error I couldn't make any suggestions.

Comment: Hello, I just set `[RequestSizeLimit(long.MaxValue)]` and the problem is gone. But for files larger than 3GB I think @Panagiotis Kanavos made some good suggestions underneath my post in the comments section

Comment: @Julian I don't quite see why `RequestSizeLimit` would have any effect as that's the limit for the size of the HTTP request to your server, not the HTTP response.

Comment: I do not know, but setting it, resolved the error